# PC shuts down automatically after a few seconds

Tags: shutdown

My custom built PC:

- Intel DH67BL
- Core i7 2600
- Asus 5670 GPU
- 500W PSU
- 2 x 500G WD Blue HDD
- 2 x 4G Transcend RAM

...was working fine for a few weeks but now I'm having this strange issue:

1. If its left untouched for a few hours, then I turn it ON, it boots up abd shows the Intel logo, it even goes into BIOS if I want and sometimes even tries to load the OS... but after a few seconds or sometimes minutes it turns OFF automatically.
2. Once I have let it boot for a few times or even once, it won't show anything on the screen, no intel logo, nothing at all!
3. If I wait another few hours and they try again, I get the display on screen again!

This is what I tried so far:

1. Tried each RAM stick one by one.
2. Tried another PSU
3. Refitted the CPU Fan
4. Managed to get into BIOS and checked temperates, nothing was worrying, all under 50 degrees. I could check only for a minute or two before it shut down automatically.

Some people I talked to said I need to reapply thermal paste, but this PC was built just 2 months back and unused since, how could the thermal paste dry up so soon? Probably because of NOT using it continuously for a few weeks?

I'd really appreciate any help!

Thanks heaps.

Comment: Sounds like some hardware problem. Did you also try the ram sticks in different slots? Unplug all devices and cards which currently aren't in use. Try to do some BIOS reset (you can do this using some jumper, have a look at you board's manual).

Comment: Did you actually try running a RAM check? What about booting windows with automcatic restart disabled?

Comment: The fact that you claim to have refitted the CPU fan but not to have reapplied thermal paste worries me. How can you refit a CPU fan without reapplying thermal paste?

Answer (score 0):

can you try another motherboard or bring it to a repair shop that has another board to try with your hardware. that is at least where i would start, but we are resellers of hardware so we have boards to test with, if this is not an option i would suggest having someone that has access to spare parts to test with. this does happen time to time, and we have had issues with direct intel based boards from intel vs other manuf like asus and gigabyte.

Answer (score 0):

How did you refit CPU fan without checking thermal paste? Any way you should check it especially if it's not coming out from under the fan on to the socket. Don't forget to plug in the fan, some motherboard want start without it. If it works after few hours something is probably overheating. If you checked properly all those things you listed it's probably the motherboard. If it's not on warranty you'll probably end up buying a new one.